# About the definition of super Hilbert Spaces

Tags: hilbert-space, conventions, fermions, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

I have found in the literature at least two different definitions of $\bf{super}$ Hilbert spaces:

1. **Definition 1:** A super Hilbert space is a complex super-vector space $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_0\oplus \mathcal{H}_1$ with a inner product such that $$\overline{\langle v,v'\rangle}=(-1)^{|v||v'|}\langle v',v\rangle.$$ Here $v$ and $v'$ are homogeneous elements. It implies that   $\mathcal{H}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}_1$ are perpendicular and that the norm square of an even vector is real and for an odd one is pure imaginary.
2. **Definition 2:** A super Hilbert space is a complex super-vector space $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_0\oplus \mathcal{H}_1$ with an inner product such that $\mathcal{H}$ is a usual Hilbert space and $\mathcal{H}_0$ is perpendicular to $\mathcal{H}_1$.

It is clear that there is a bijective correspondence between this two kind of super Hilbert spaces. If $\mathcal{H}$ satisfies definition 1, then only changing the inner product in the odd elements as $\langle v',v''\rangle' = \overline{\langle v',v''\rangle}$ you get a super Hilbert space of definition 2.

**My question is**: Which is the most used definition in physics and why?

Comment: If the definitions are equivalent, then how could you say that we use one, but not the other?

Comment: It sounds like def 2 is more natural, at least I'm more used to norm square of any states being positive definite.

Comment: Why should $H_0$ and $H_1$ be perpendicular w.r.t. the inner product?

Comment: Which literature?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Worth talking about nevertheless, I think. Confused [not only me](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315757/), but [people who write books on the stuff](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Evv5-QA-Ww8C&lpg=PA159&ots=-J1TDESezC&pg=PA159) as well (compare with first link).