# Two conjugations of supernumbers

Tags: supersymmetry, conventions, complex-numbers, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

Let $\theta$ and $\eta$ denote odd complex supernumbers (also known as Grassmann numbers), $a$ and $b$ arbitrary complex supernumbers. Say that $a$ is $\circ$-real (resp. $\circ$-imaginary) if $a^\circ = a$ (resp. $a^\circ = -a$).

There are two candidates for the role of $(-)^\circ$, *i.e.* two ways to define conjugation of supernumbers: with $(\theta\eta)^* = \theta^*\eta^*$ and with $(\theta\eta)^\dagger = \eta^\dagger\theta^\dagger$. (Notation from [Cartier and DeWitt-Morette](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Evv5-QA-Ww8C&lpg=PA159&ots=-J1TDESezC&pg=PA159#v=onepage&q&f=false), who define both, see Eq. (9.13).) Note that:

- the product $\theta\eta$ is $*$-real when $\theta$ and $\eta$ are $*$-real, while $\theta^*\theta$ is $*$-imaginary;
- the product $\theta\eta$ is $\dagger$-imaginary when $\theta$ and $\eta$ are $\dagger$-real, while $\theta^\dagger\theta$ is $\dagger$-real.

Physicists usually use $(-)^\dagger$, motivating this by the correspondence with Hermitian conjugation of operators through quantization. Two places that use $(-)^*$ are the [*draft* chapter 9](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/dls/DLSCartierCh9.pdf)<sup>PDF</sup> of Cartier and DeWitt-Morette (again) and *Quantum fields and strings* by Deligne *et al.*, see their “[Sign manifesto](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/79_SignManifesto.pdf)”<sup>PDF</sup>. The latter say about their choice (notation adjusted to match):

> This is a consequence of the sign rule if we assume that $\theta\mapsto\theta^*$ is a $*$*-operation* and $\theta$ (super)commutes with $\eta$. (A $*$-operation satisfies $(ab)^* = (-1)^{\lvert a\rvert\lvert b\rvert} b^*a^*$.) Notice that the classical statement (34) is consistent with the quantum statement (19), since the adjoint operation on linear operators is also a $*$-operation.

Eq. (34) is the definition of $(-)^*$, and (19) is the statement that quantizing complex conjugates yields Hermitian conjugates.

That is, *both* camps say that their choice is the one that behaves properly under quantization! What am I missing?

**Edit:** To add insult to injury, [Rogers](https://books.google.fr/books?id=itmfZTZCm_MC&lpg=PR2&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false) section 3.3 defines a conjugation similar to $(-)^\dagger$, but with an $i$ before odd terms in the reality condition; see discussion in [Cook](https://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/handle/1840.16/5690) section 2.10. She also references [Kleppe and Wainwright](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0501252), who define what they call a “pseudo-conjugation” alongside $(-)^\dagger$ and get some interesting group theory from there—it is *not* involutive, though. [Pellegrini](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311240), also doing group theory, compares the same “pseudo-conjugation” with $(-)^*$.

Comment: Related questions: [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203019/55657) (reversed order for $(-)^\dagger$) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263979/55657) (left derivatives become right under $(-)^\dagger$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in [how the Hermitian product and conjugation are defined](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189481/) in the quantized theory. The usual physicist’s definitions do not use the super structure on the Hilbert space and imply
$$
  \langle u, v\rangle = \overline{\langle v, u\rangle},\quad
  \langle u, u\rangle\geq 0,\quad
  \langle u, Tv\rangle =\langle T^\dagger u, v\rangle.
$$
The definitions used by Deligne *et al.*, on the other hand, involve the parity $\lvert-\rvert$ explicitly:
$$
  (u, v) = (-1)^{\lvert u\rvert\lvert v\rvert}\overline{(v, u)},\quad
  (-i)^{\lvert u\rvert}(u, u)\geq 0,\quad
  (u, Tv) = (-1)^{\lvert u\rvert\lvert T\rvert}(T^*u, v).
$$

Now let $e$ and $f$ be even vectors (bosonic states), $\omicron$ and $\pi$ odd vectors (fermionic states). Then the correspondence between the products is
$$
  (e,f) = \langle e,f\rangle,\quad
  (\omicron, \pi) = i\langle\omicron,\pi\rangle.
$$
As for the conjugation, let $P$ be an even operator and $Q$ an odd operator. Then
\begin{align}
  \langle P^\dagger e, f\rangle =\langle e,Pf\rangle = (e, Pf) &= +(P^*e, f) = +\langle P^* e, f\rangle,\\
  i\langle P^\dagger\omicron,\pi\rangle = i\langle\omicron, P\pi\rangle = (\omicron, P\pi) &= +(P^*\omicron,\pi) = +i\langle P^*\omicron,\pi\rangle;\\
  \langle Q^\dagger e,\omicron\rangle =\langle e,Q\omicron\rangle = (e,Q\omicron) &= +(Q^*e,\omicron) = +i\langle Q^*e,\omicron\rangle,\\
  i\langle Q^\dagger\omicron, e\rangle = i\langle\omicron, Qe\rangle = (\omicron, Qe) &= -(Q^*\omicron,e) = -\langle Q^*\omicron,e\rangle;
\end{align}
whence
$$
  P^\dagger = P^*,\quad Q^\dagger = iQ^*,
$$
and therefore
$$
  (ST)^* = (1/i)^{\lvert ST\rvert}(ST)^\dagger = (1/i)^{\lvert ST\rvert}T^\dagger S^\dagger = (1/i)^{\lvert ST\rvert}i^{\lvert S\rvert}i^{\lvert T\rvert}T^*S^* = (-1)^{\lvert S\rvert +\lvert T\rvert}T^*S^*.
$$

This indeed agrees with the proper definition ([Leites *et al.*, 2011](http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/2011-sos1.pdf)<sup>Russian PDF</sup> Sect. 1.11; [Berezin and Shubin, 1999](http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/berezin-shubin-1991-shroedinger.djvu)<sup>English DjVu</sup> Supplement 3 [[MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=93i:81001)]) of a real structure in a complex superalgebra,
$$
  (ab)^* = (-1)^{\lvert a\rvert +\lvert b\rvert}b^* a^*,
$$
which coincides with $(ab)^* = a^*b^*$ in the supercommutative (classical) case.

The peculiar definitions of Rogers are due to the fact that she uses $(-)^\dagger$ as the conjugation but her real elements are the $*$-real ones (using the correspondence $a^\dagger = i^{\lvert a\rvert}a^*$ established for operators above). The “pseudo-conjugation” of Kleppe and Wainwright and of Pellegrini is what Leites *et al.* call a quaternionic structure; they also establish that these are the only interesting semilinear (super)involutions of this type up to a real superalgebra automorphism.

Finally, note that while $\zeta^*\zeta$ is not real for odd complex $\zeta$, $\{\zeta^*,\zeta\}/2\equiv\bigl(\zeta^*\zeta + (-1)^{\lvert\zeta^*\rvert\lvert\zeta\rvert}\zeta\zeta^*\bigr)/2$ is.